# cluster external validation

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan, elki, optics-algorithm

I am using ELKI in order to perform location clustering with DBSCAN and OPTICS. My data set include 30 participants but it is not labeled but I do have pair of coordinates (e.g. home, work, etc) as each participant's frequent places.

I want to know that these pair of coordinates belong to which cluster (for each person). One of the way is to check each pair against each of the cluster manually using some minimum distance threshold.

What could be the better way to achieve this?

Comment: I do not understand your objective.

Comment: Actually I want to validate the clusters against the ground truth.

Comment: The data is not labeled but I do know the frequent locations of people, on average each person has 4 to 6 different locations.

Comment: Can't you then generate labels from the frequent locations?

Comment: but how do I compare that e.g. home corresponds to cluster X?

Comment: The usual evaluation measures will "align" labels to clusters. But they cannot define "home", you need to provide such labels.

Comment: Would you like to provide pointers about how to provide the labels?

Comment: Add a column with the label (as *text*) to your data set. ELKI then automatically evaluates the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115209/discussion-between-user1124825-and-anony-mousse).

Comment: It is not nice. Anyways thanks for the time!

Answer (score 2):

Can you format your input data as this:

```
123 456 work1
124 457 work1
789 123 home2
123 123 unknown
```

The labels should be non numeric, that's why I chose "work1", "work2" etc. for this example.

Then ELKI can automatically evaluate the result.